# Что лучше, веб-служба .asmx или служба WCF?

Tags: asp.net, веб-служба, .net, wcf

Прошу дать сравнительный анализ. Стоит ли применять asmx в проектах на .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF предоставляет абстракцию от протокола передачи данных. Кроме того, WCF позволяет более гибко управлять форматом сообщений.

С другой стороны, с asmx меньше проблем в плане настройки масштабируемости. В WCF Вы будете постоянно бороться с таймаутами на ровном месте, а Web Services нормально работают прямо из коробки.

Comment: Где-то читал, что `WCF` пришла на смену `веб-службам`. Последние использовать только для поддержки старых служб. При создании новых, применять `WCF`. А что за таймауты на ровном месте?

Comment: Там настройки нагрузки по умолчанию довольно жёсткие. Где-то я читал статью о чёрном тестировании этих технологий, и Web Services выдавали лучшие результаты. Сейчас ссылку на эту статью я не нашёл. В общем, если хватает Web Services, лучше использовать их.

Comment: Буду рад, если сможете предоставить эту ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

В этих двух англоязычных топиках про это говорится:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/wcf-vs-asmx-web-service

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229705/asmx-versus-wcf

PS: если что, могу перевести

Comment: Особо вникать не стал, плохо знаю язык. Смысл понятен, лучше использовать `WCF`. А для решения [этой задачи](http://hashcode.ru/questions/74128/клиент-для-веб-службы-asp-net), что лучше?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что и для этой задачи лучше WCF. Тем более, что, судя по сказанному Википедии, WCF позволяет обернуть собой те же asmx. Но я в веб-технологиях совершенное не разбираюсь, так что можно меня не слушать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.